# how to strip json comments in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

How to strip json comments in javascript ?
I think a regex will be a concise way.

```
{
    "filed": { // comments
         "n": 1 /* multi-line ...
                                 comments */
    },
    "field2": " // comments in string , /* here */ "
}
```

should work on the above example.
Note: the comments in the string should **not** be removed.

**Update**: i know that comments in json are not valid, but for simplicity i want to have them and then remove them, i see a lot of tools support parsing jsons which have comments.

**Update 2**: the above example itself is a string, i didn't explain that (sorry), and now see some answers thinking its a js code.

**Update 3**: i again forgot to put keynames in double quotes, updated the question.

Comment: Why do you have comments in a json? that json is invalid...

Comment: updated the question @taxicala

Comment: If you want to go the regex route, `(\/\*[\S\s]*?\*\/)|(\/\/[^\n]*)` might work: https://regex101.com/r/fJ1aC6/1

Comment: @dustmouse no it can't be that simple, let me think about the above regex.

Comment: with or without comments - it is **not** JSON, it is an object literal.

Comment: @davidkonrad i know that comments are not valid in json, but i am working on a .json file and i load it via $.get() , i want to strip the comments in my .json file before parsing it. its not the only time had this problem, i know it is not josn, call it what ever you want.

Comment: Can I expect it to have double quotes? @AminRoosta

Comment: What about evil... I mean eval

Comment: @AminRoosta, it is an object literal. JSON **must** have quoted keynames - it will fail in JSONlint, fail with  `JSON.parse() ` and everything else ... So it is simply a literal you can  `eval() `...

Comment: @OlaviSau double quotes are considered standard, so yes.

Comment: @davidkonrad you are right about this, updated the question (sorry)

Comment: I just wrote a little helper for this: [decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574731/vscode-delete-all-comments-in-a-file "VSCode: delete all comments in a file") has more possible regexes.

Answer (score 15):

While commenting in JSON is not a standard practice, in some cases it could be useful. For this purpose I wrote small package for nodejs: [json-easy-strip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-easy-strip)

Your JSON file could contain any valid JS comments:

```
{
    /*
     * Sweet section
     */
    "fruit": "Watermelon", // Yes, watermelons is sweet!
    "dessert": /* Yummy! */ "Cheesecake",
    // And finally
    "drink": "Milkshake - /* strawberry */ or // chocolate!" // Mmm...
}
```

And here is how we strip it:

```js
//
// Our JSON string
let jsonString = `{
    /*
     * Sweet section
     */
    "fruit": "Watermelon", // Yes, watermelons is sweet!
    "dessert": /* Yummy! */ "Cheesecake",
    // And finally
    "drink": "Milkshake - /* strawberry */ or // chocolate!" // Mmm...
}`;

//
// One-liner comment stripper
jsonString = jsonString.replace(/\\"|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)/g, (m, g) => g ? "" : m);

//
// Parse jsonString and print result
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));

//
// Result
//  {
//    fruit: "Watermelon",
//    dessert: "Cheesecake",
//    drink: "Milkshake - /* strawberry */ or // chocolate!"
//  }
```

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is to run `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse` and voila it's clean.

Comment: Not if your JSON is more like JavaScript or JSON5, then it won't work, i.e. JSON that uses open-name properties, or regular expressions for values.

Answer (score 3):

Let the javascript parser do it:

```
a = {
    filed: { // comments
         n: 1 /* multi-line ...
                                 comments */
    },
    field2: " // comments in string , /* here */ "
}
a.toSource()
/*
({filed:{n:1}, field2:" // comments in string , /* here */ "})
*/
```

You could do it with a string (according to the edited question) the very same way:

```
a =   'a = {\r\n  filed: { // comments  n: 1 \r\n/* multi-line ...  comments */\r\n},\r\n'
    + 'field2: " // comments in string , /* here */ "\r\n}'
eval(a).toSource().toString();
```

But it doesn't seem to work with chrome? Oh, forgot, it is FF only, sorry (in Javascript version 3).

I found a replacement at https://gist.github.com/archan937/1961799 so the following works in most of the rest of the browsers, too.

```
function inspect(object) {
  switch (typeof(object)) {
  case "undefined":
    return "undefined";
  case "string":
    return "\"" + object.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\"/g, "\\\"") + "\"";
  case "object":
    if (object == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    var a = [];
    if (object instanceof Array) {
      for (var i in object) {
        a.push(inspect(object[i]));
      };
      return "[" + a.join(", ") + "]";
    } else {
      for (var key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          a.push(key + ": " + inspect(object[key]));
        }
      };
      return "{" + a.join(", ") + "}";
    }
  default:
    return object.toString();
  }
};

a = 'a = {\r\n  filed: { // comments  n: 1 \r\n/* multi-line ...  comments */\r\n},\r\n'
    + 'field2: " // comments in string , /* here */ "\r\n}'

alert(inspect(eval(a)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove comments, with support for JSON5, have a look at library [decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment).

It can remove comments from JSON5, JavaScript ES6, CSS and HTML, in the same simple way.

```
var decomment = require('decomment');

var code = "var t; // comments";

decomment(code); //=> var t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a personal opinion, if you want to keep an invalid JSON full of comments for production purposes, I suppose its up to you, but deploying that stuff to your live website and then filling it with JavaScript hacks to make it work doesn't look good at all. I suggest you generate a clean JSON file for deployment, and keep the commented code to yourself. The end user doesn't have to see that, and he certainly doesn't need a bunch of indenting spaces increasing amount of data transfered aswell.

In any case, here is one way of removing those comments:

```
var invalid_json = "{\n\"filed\": { // comments\n\"n\": 1 /* multi-line ...\ncomments */\n},\n\"field2\": \" // comments in string , /* here */ \"\n}";

eval("var x = " + invalid_json);
var x = JSON.stringify(x);
alert(x); // x should be valid JSON of that
```

Another way is to use it as JavaScript instead of JSON, you will just have to modify the file a bit:

```
// file.js
var data = {
    "filed": { // comments
         "n": 1 /* multi-line ...
                                 comments */
    },
    "field2": " // comments in string , /* here */ "
};
```

In the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

This should import the object to your page with the name `data`.

Comment: Just my opinion: when u say "generate a clean JSON file for deployment" – that adds complexity to already complex build tools, and needs maintenance as yr build tools get upgraded. For me there's no harm in throwing a few extra bytes around if it keeps things simple. +Thanks for the `eval` hack, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of answers using `eval`. While these methods work, using `eval` can be risky. Though these ways certainly pose no threat, I advocate to never use `evel`, even for simple things like this.

Here's my adaptation of Havenard's answer that uses a similar, but different method.

```js
var invalid_json = "{\n\"filed\": { // comments\n\"n\": 1 /* multi-line ...\ncomments */\n},\n\"field2\": \" // comments in string , /* here */ \"\n}";

var json = (new Function("return " + invalid_json))();
var x = JSON.stringify(json);
alert(x); // x should be valid JSON of that
```