# VSCode: delete all comments in a file

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

Is there an easy way to delete all Java-style & C-style comments from an open file in VSCode? Preferably both line and block comments.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

#### Easy way:

- Open extensions (ctrl-shift-x)
- type in `remove comments` in the search box.
- Install the top pick and read instructions.

#### Hard way:

- search replace(ctrl-h)
- toggle regex on (alt-r).
- Learn some regular expressions! https://docs.rs/regex/0.2.5/regex/#syntax

A simple `//.*` will match all single line comments (and more ;D). `#.*` could be used to match python comments.  And `/\*[\s\S\n]*\*/` matches block comments.  And you can combine them as well: `//.*|/\*[\s\S\n]*\*/` (`|` in regex means "or", `.` means any character, `*` means "0 or more" and indicates how many characters to match, therefore `.*` means all characters until the end of the line (or until the next matching rule))

Of course with caveats, such as urls (`https://...`) has double slashes and will match that first rule, and god knows where there are `#` in code that will match that python-rule. So some reading/adjusting has to be done!

Once you start fiddling with your regexes it can take a lifetime to get them perfect, so be careful and go the easy route if you are short on time, but knowing some simple regex by heart will do you good, since regular expressions are usable almost everywhere.

Comment: Regex really helped me. I think these are very powerful. God bless you.

Comment: Make the set non-greedy otherwise if there are two block comments it will also grab the code in between the two `//.*|/\*[\s\S\n]*?\*/`

Comment: Ideal for simple single-line CSS-Comments, it kills also empty spaces and lines before. 
`^(\s+)?//.*\n?`

Comment: `regexes it can take a lifetime to get perfect`

Comment: Be very careful with regexes for such tasks. I tried them out in my project and it caused a lot of side effects. For example an URL in a string will break the whole code.

Comment: better not to use the top-pick by `plibither8` it does not scan for strings, does not remove the resulting empty lines, only handles C/C++/Java(Script) comments and is not supported anymore

Answer (score 21):

This will be an easy way. Type CTRL + F and type `//.*` and select the regex sign like the below picture.

[image]

Now you can see all the commented lines are selected. Replace those with space. Replace can enable click with **>** sign in the above picture.

[image]

for the second text field enter a space and press enter. It will remove commented lines one by one. By giving a long press you can delete all commented lines.

Comment: Is there a way only select lines that have no space after #,  e.g.```#df.to_excel(..)``` and keep things like ```# read in data```

Comment: @asd try according to this answer `#[^\s].*` to have no whitespace after `#`

Comment: In the replace field I do not need a space. Hiting enter will clear the line. By hitting long time `enter`, the lines are deleted line by line. Your solution helps even more if auto formatting is set in the editor.

Answer (score 6):

work for me

Type `CTRL + F` and type `//.*`

This image describe bette

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

Html Comment Remove:

1. Search: `<!--.*-->`
2. and Replace All

Comment: Search and Replace by pressing `ctrl +h` and also remember to turn Regex on.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't comment (not enough reputation) but to complete **ippi** response :
You can add a look behind condition for the single-line comments regex to avoid including URLs such as http(s)://

Example :

```
(?<=[^:])\/\/.*
```

So th complete regex would look like :

```
(?<=[^:])\/\/.*|/\*[\s\S\n]*\*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work pretty well for me with block comments:

```
/\*[\s\S\n].*
```

Comment: This is a REGEX answer, not a VS Code answer

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to remove all print and commented print statement in a file.

I used this regx to remove all print statement in a file

- Find **^(\s*)print.***
- and Replace with blank

I used this regx to remove all commented print statement in a file

- Find **^(\s*)//print.***
- and Replace with blank

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the comments in my tsconfig.json due to a bug with [tslint-to-eslint-config](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config/issues/742); The [fix is merged](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config/pull/755) now FYI.

But I solved it by turning on regex search mode in vscode, and entering this into the search field:

```regex
(\/\/.*| ?\/\*.+\*\/)(,?)$`
```

and this into the replace field:

```
$2
```

you can see this working on regex101.com (with replacement) [here](https://regex101.com/r/n5XTe1/2)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will look for `#` symbols that are not immediately preceded or followed by single or double quotes, which helps avoid removing `#` symbols that are part of a string.

```
(?<!['"])(\s*#.*)(?!\s*['"])
```

skip remove in this format

```
f.write(f'#ABCD\n')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Regex is already part of the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 0):

[replace tab in vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxNKV.png)

this worked for me

replace `//.*\r?\n`

with `\n`

this way your codelines will be safe and only comments disappear

Comment: Can you provide a brief explanation of the regex?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to install an extension which removes selected comments, you can try this approach,

- Ctrl F to find on a page
- Find //
- Replace with *blank*
- Go through the find and your // comments will be replaced with blanks therefore removing your comments! :)