# How to delete all comments and/or white spaces and/or null lines in a *.vue file

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

How to delete all comments and/or white spaces and/or null lines in a *.vue file.

I have searched online, and there is no solution. Only one I have found is: [VSCode: delete all comments in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574731/vscode-delete-all-comments-in-a-file)

It suggested a vscode plugin called remove comments, but this plugin does not work on *.vue file.

The second way it suggested is regex.. But I don't know much about regex.

Is there any good way to delete all comments and/or white spaces and/or null lines in a *.vue file?

Comment: @tony19 unwanted white spaces.

Comment: Define "unwanted"

Comment: @tony19 For example like this: "    (some unwanted white spaces)     <!-- some unwanted comments-->"

Comment: From your example, I assume you mean **leading whitespace** (but probably also **trailing whitespace**).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) and [Eslint](https://eslint.org/). You could run it from terminal or add proper script to your package.json file

Comment: Thank you. I tried Prettier in it's playground https://prettier.io/playground/ I didn't an option for delete comments?...

Comment: You need to config prettier the [way](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html) it will take eslint rules. And you could add this rule in elsint.

Comment: Thank you again, it looks not easy to config but I will have a try... But I'm still concerned does it can actually remove all comments? Because the prettier's documentation does not mention deleting comments at all... I want to delete all the like  <!-- <div class="text1"> -->  and all the // in the vue file. Does it really work for this purpose?

Comment: If I need to delete comments in html template, I would find all of them by global search (ctrl+shift+f) and then replace it with empty string. Prettier doesn't help with that I guess

Comment: ok, you mean using regex to delete comments in html template section and script section separately? Will they conflict? How to prevent accidentally delete unwanted areas...

Comment: Comments in html is different typing