# Custom php Hide programmer's comments from public view

Tags: php, html

When we create a html page comments like

```
<!-- Comment 1 -->
```

or inside php

> // Comment2

are obvious from a right click of the page - Show code

How can i prevent that ?

Comment: It is possible to remove comments completely if you are running `output buffering` as you can assign a callback that does whatever tasks yo want to the page before rendering

Comment: PHP comments are not visible in the HTML page source.

Comment: So i could write a hidden comment like this ? <html>  <?php //Comment Hidden ?> </html ?

Comment: yes, with php(-comments) you could hide your comments for public

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the comments inside  is the answer.. Thanks everyone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Html comments will show on the HTML page but as long as you include your PHP comments in the `<?php` tag they won't show to the `user`

To leave html comments are normal if you check amazon.com's code you will see all the html comments but none php or whatever server lang they use so don't worry about html comments just don't include stupid stuff like your admin password or some revealing database schema stuff in the html comments.

***if you still want to remove all the comments even html(vscode):***

> #### Easy way:
>
> - Open extensions (ctrl-shift-x)  * type in `remove comments` in the
>   search box.   * Install the top pick and read instructions.
>
> #### Hard way:  * search replace(ctrl-h)  * toggle regex on (alt-r).   * Learn some regular expressions! https://docs.rs/regex/0.2.5/regex/#syntax
>
> A simple `//.*` will match all single line comments (and more ;D).
> `#.*` could be used to match python comments.  And `/\*[\s\S\n]*\*/`
> matches block comments.  And you can combine them as well:
> `//.*|/\*[\s\S\n]*\*/` (`|` in regex means "or", `.` means any
> character, `*` means "0 or more" and indicates how many characters to
> match, therefore `.*` means all characters until the end of the line
> (or until the next matching rule))
>
> Of course with caveats, such as urls (`https://...`) has double
> slashes and will match that first rule, and god knows where there are
> `#` in code that will match that python-rule. So some
> reading/adjusting has to be done!
>
> Once you start fiddling with your regexes it can take a lifetime to
> get them perfect, so be careful and go the easy route if you are short
> on time, but knowing some simple regex by heart will do you good,
> since regular expressions are usable almost everywhere.
> From https://stackoverflow.com/a/50575194/17239314