# How to remove all/multiple comments in a Flutter file at once?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, comments, shortcut

How do I remove all the the comments in this file at once ?
I don't wanna go line by line and erase all the comments or select an area + backspace multiple times.
Is there any shortcut?
[code with comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d61io.png)

[code without comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3S3q.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode: delete all comments in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574731/vscode-delete-all-comments-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which doesn't need any extension.

To remove all the comments together at once using Regular Expression. 
Rejex mode will be enabled by clicking on .*
Then in VS Code:

`Press Ctrl + H Press Alt + R //.* Press tab Press Ctrl + Alt + Enter Press Ctrl + S`

Comment: what if you have a URL in a string: `"http://www.google.com"`, this is the "solution" that the extension `plibither8.remove-comments` uses. It has a lot of complains that it deletes stuff it should not have deleted.

Comment: it is the same answer that OlegBezr gave and deleted and flagged the question as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to remove the comments if you did not create them in the first place. You can create a new Flutter project without comments following these steps:

1. open `Command Palette` in VS Code
2. type `Flutter: New Project`
3. select `Flutter Application (empty)`

or simple use the command `flutter create my_app -e`. For details, you can refer to the `flutter create --help` command.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the extension [Remove Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-remove-comments) and it supports Dart

Comment: can I do it without installing any extension ?

Comment: @Shinchandler No, you have to analyze the strings if they contain comment characters, finding a regex to do it is very hard to impossible.

Comment: Hey I just posted the solution without using any extension, check it out !